# How to create progress dialog while executing task and after complete task dialog should be dismiss?

Tags: dart, flutter, async-await

**How do I add Progressbar?**

After click button, I need to display a progress bar while executing the task and after complete task, the dialog should be dismissed and move to next page if successful login.

in Raised Button:

```
onPressed: () async {
  (isOffline)
  ? showSnackBar(context)
  : checkingValidation(usernameController, context, _url);
}


checkingValidation(TextEditingController usernameController, BuildContext context, String _url) async {
if(....){
...
}else{
    Navigator.push(
       context,
       MaterialPageRoute(
       builder: (context) => HomePage()))
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `Stack` and inside that use alert dialog as you want.
Add a flag like `bool showProgress`, whenever you need a progress alert dialog to be shown or hide just set `showProgress=true` or `showProgress=false` respectively in `setState` to show or hide the alert dialog widget.

or simply use this template I created.

```
  static showProgressDialog(BuildContext context, String title) {
    try {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          barrierDismissible: false,
          builder: (context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              content: Flex(
                direction: Axis.horizontal,
                children: <Widget>[
                  CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),),
                  Flexible(
                      flex: 8,
                      child: Text(
                        title,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      )),
                ],
              ),
            );
          });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

when you want to show this just call 
`AppUtils.showProgressDialog(context, "Please wait");`

when you have done task, just call `Navigator.pop(context);`

You can create a class as `AppUtils` and place this template in class, so you can reuse this anywhere in your app.

Comment: as I said, create a class with any name as you want e.g. `AppUtils` put that function in that class. Then whenever you need to show progress dialog, just call `AppUtils.showProgressDialog(context, "Please wait");` whenever you finished with the task call `Navigator.pop` to close alert dialog

Comment: thanks. It's working well. But I confused because I called AppUtils when clicking a button and every single validation statement I called navigator.pop

Comment: not getting what the issue, can you explain and add some code.

Comment: `checking2(TextEditingController usernameController, BuildContext context, String _url) async {
  AppUtils.showProgressDialog(context, "Please wait");`

Comment: **every single showDialog** `if (model.data.hasAccess == 0) {
          Navigator.pop(context);
          showDialog(`

Comment: you can take `Navigator.pop` at the end of the function and show another dialog. which will reduce repeated code.

Comment: I added..it's working.but showDialog message not displayed.

Comment: `showDialog` after `Navigator.pop` for progress dialog